# Nice visual HTML5 effect for drop zone?

Tags: html, css, drag-and-drop

I have implemented a web application with an html5-based drag&drop upload function.

Now I am looking for a nice effect to work as a drop invitation, showing the user where she can drop the dragged files.

I saw some examples where opacity is reduced, but since I'm on HTML5 and CSS3, much nicer effects should be possible.

I had a look at http://css-plus.com/2012/03/gaussian-blur/ but that's only for images...

EDIT:
To be more concrete:
The whole application is ExtJS-based and the drop zone is a Grid.
I can image a nice blur effect on the grid (like shown in the given link)...

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Sascha.

Comment: This question is a bit off topic for SO I believe. If you are looking for the most intuitive effect to use from a user perspective, the question might be more suitable on [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Indeed, I wasn't aware of that site...

Comment: On the other hand, I am not only asking for an intuitive effect, but also a really nice on, i.e. some concrete CSS suggestions...

Comment: To be a good SO question, I believe it would be better if you knew what kind of effect you were looking for, so that you could describe it in your question. The answers could then offer ways to achieve that effect through CSS. Like that, the question would be about programming (good for SO), and not so much about design (off topic for SO).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS3 filter: See http://html.adobe.com/webplatform/graphics/customfilters/cssfilterlab/ for demos.

Just apply: `-webkit-filter: blur(3px);` to your CSS. Vendor prefix as needed. Just know that compatibility it not very good: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters